# What are the necessary and sufficient conditions for a polynomial with domain the positive integers to always produce an integer?

Tags: polynomials, integer-sequences

Let $n\in Z^+$ and $poly(n)$ be a polynomial with domain $Z^+$. Then what are the necessary and sufficient conditions in regards to the coefficients of $poly(n)$ for the following to hold?

$poly(n):Z^+\rightarrow Z$

Is it simply that the coefficients are integers? Or are there, for example, polynomials with some non-integer rational coefficients that always produce an integer?

Comment: A very interesting problem. One counter example is $P(x)=\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x}{2}$. This is evident since $x(x+1)$ is always even.

Comment: By a simple side argument, if a polynomial takes integer values on all positive integers (in fact, on any $n+1$ consecutive integers, where $n$ is the degree) it does so on all integers, see e.g. [Cameron's Blog](https://cameroncounts.wordpress.com/2017/01/31/polynomials-taking-integer-values/). Then, by Polya-Ostrowski, it is an integral linear combination of binomial coefficients ${x\choose k},\:$ taken as polynomials in $x$. The converse is obvious.